# How to insert data into Oracle Database using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

Hi Below is the code what i am trying to do the connection string is fine , when i run this No Error pops out and neither it updating the DB
Can you Please help me identify the error.

and i have Two sheet inside that excel data is same just one more column in second sheet name as gender

```
sample Dataframe which i want to insert into DB is 
    NAME  AGE
0    x   21
1    y   22
2    z   23
3    m   24
4    t   35



import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import  create_engine

engine = Create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://<Connection Detail>')

DB_Connection = cx_Oracle.connect(<Connection Detail)
mycursor = DB_Connection.cursor()

sample_excel = pd.ExcelFile(r<file Path>)
sample_excel_sheet = sample_excel.sheet_names


for i in sample_excel_sheet:
  
    sheet_data = pd.read_excel(r<file Path>,sheet_name=i)

    sheet_namee = i.upper()
    
    with engine.connect() as connection:                
            sheet_data.to_sql(name='sheet_namee',con=engine, if_exists='replace')  
        
                
                
DB_Connection.commit()
```

Comment: ```sheet_namee``` return  'MYSHEET'  if the sheet name is ```MYSHEET```. Have you tried to simply write ```name=sheet_namee```  in ´´´sheet_data.to_sql(name='sheet_namee',con=engine, if_exists='replace')```?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply 
yes i did try it will create a table with the name as sheet_namee in DB if i pass sheet_namee without inverted commas

Comment: and even i tried printing the to_sql statement while storing it in a var it printed as NONE. I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change

```
name='sheet_namee'
```

with

```
name=sheet_namee
```

since `sheet_namee = i.upper()` already returns the sheet name with inverted commas.

Comment: i understand Thankyou
but name=sheet_namee returns the lower case sheet name into upper case
it isn't returning the sheet name with inverted commas